# Unable to set Entry Point in Mage?

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-installer, clickonce, mage

I am using Mage.exe for creating a Click Once Deployment for my winform application. After I have browsed the files and clicked on the populate button I am unable to select any file as the Entry point.

[image]

and this results in the **The customHostSpecified attribute is not supported for Windows Forms applications.** Error

I searched and found that some users have resolved this problem by using correct version of the Tool from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\mage.exe" . Since I'm using windows XP so i Tried "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\mage.exe" but this also does not work.

Can any one help me with these please.
FYI : I am using windows XP and VS2010.

**Edit**
Even If I add a single exe file even then it cannot be marked as the entry point.

I tried the command line version but even that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to set the entry point to be the setup.exe for an msi installer?  It's not obvious from the documentation but the entry point for Click Once deployment must be a .Net exe.

Comment: I don't have any MS specific documentation, but it's mentioned by several people in Stackoverflow and also on some blogs, for example: http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2008/08/25/clickonce-deployment-for-unmanaged-code-c-vb6-etc/

Answer (score 0):

If possible I would not recommend ClickOne. It has many issues.  It can fail, then you have to go on the user's computer to solve the issue. Yikes

Comment: can you elaborate what kind of issues can arise if I use clickonce

Comment: Sure. If it fails you may need to get on the user's computer and it's terribly difficult to remove the bad msi files